# Repo: Is it possible to modify "default" elements using local_manifest?

Tags: manifest, repo

I want to know if it's possible to modify the default remote, revision, etc. using a local_manifest xml.

Comment: What you mean is create a local_manifest.xml with different remote and revision, then using this manifest to download(clone) code ?

Comment: "create a local_manifest.xml with different **default** remote and revision". These defaults should then be used to clone the code of projects which do not specify any remote and revision (and hence rely on the default remote and revision).